# How to create a TS Type based on an object property and ensure type and property checking?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have this array of objects:

```
const formTest = [
   { label: "test", name: "grossSalary" },
   { label: "test", name: "privatePension" },
];
```

I'd like to build a type based on all `name` properties. So that `formTest` array would get me this type:

```
type FormValues = {
  grossSalary: string;
  privatePension: string;
}
```

Is there a way to do that and ensure type and properties checking?

For example, this should throw a TS error since `invalidProperty` doesn't exist on `FormValues`:

```
const initialValues: FormValues = {
   grossSalary: "",
   invalidProperty: "",
}
```

I've tried to use `mapped type`:

```
type FormValues = {
   [K in typeof formTest[number]["name"]]: string;
}
```

but the outcome only checks type, not properties, which doesn't throw an error in the example above.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The type of `formTest` is just `{ label: string; name: string; }[]`, at the very least you'd have to define it `as const` to preserve the types of the `name` property values: https://tsplay.dev/we6dXN.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it's not exactly what I was looing for, but it helps. Thank you!

Comment: In what way? You have to preserve the type information _somehow_.

Comment: `as const` is your only choice here